# how to switch between english and other languages while filling data in rails form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my ruby on rails application, I am accepting input in hindi language to save in mysql database. I want to make a checkbox to switch the language while entering data so I can type in hindi or english according to language selected in checkbox.

How I can do this using jQuery on unicode convertor in rails.
Help me to solve out this. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `switch the language`?

Comment: I want to allow user to type in both hindi and english language according to   language selected. text filed may contain mix data in both language at a time.

Comment: That's not a matter of any code, but a matter of the user's selected keyboard-input. I can type Danish into any text box I like, regardless of whether or not the site displays Hindi, Russian or Danish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use google transliteration https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started.

It provide keyboard input in both hindi and english language. Switching language is very easy with Ctrl+g command.
Thanks.